# SQL Server - Pivot using Variable Value in at least Two Outputs using Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, pivot

I have the below script but renders an error stating that @currentsupplierno is not defined. The `@currentsupplierno` having issue is the one on the `select from` query at `@query` part of the script.

[image]

When I run the script, I wanted to achieve the below. (Yes, both output with header because my teammates need to copy output separately, not as one table.)  I hope this doesn't confuse you. I'm pretty new to SQL.

Also, the number of Suppliers might increase, so it isn't fixed to the below two. Add to it, I've stored all supplier numbers in an array (because this is a super input) which is used to further filter a table which contains the identified SupplierName, PeriodID and CalculatedDollars on the sample data below.

[image]

using the below sample data:

[image]

```
while exists (select SupplierNo from @supplier)

BEGIN

declare @currentsupplierno int

select top 1 @currentSupplierno = SupplierNo
from @supplier
order by supplierNo ASC

declare @col nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select @col = STUFF(
        (select distinct ',', quotename(periodID) 
         from #WeeklySales
         order by 1,2
         for xml path (''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

set @query = 'select SupplierNo,SupplierName,' + @col + ' 
    into #WeeklySales
    from (select SupplierNo,SupplierName, periodID, CalculatedDollars from #WeeklySales WHERE supplierno = @currentsupplierno) sq pivot (sum(CalculatedDOLLARS) for periodID IN (' + @col + ')) pt' 

print @query
execute (@query)

delete from @supplier where supplierno = @currentsupplierno
end
```

Comment: What is the issue in above query? It seems fine

Comment: @DarkRob updated the post for the error I'm getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead of `execute()` to be able to pass parameters into a dynamic query.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql   
          @query,  
          N'@currentsupplierno int',  
          @currentsupplierno;
```